# Stored procedure parameter default value

Tags: stored-procedures, ssms

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with default parameters, in my query I would do it like this:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
DECLARE @MT DATETIME
DECLARE @MY DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT @MT = DATEPART(MONTH,@mydate)
SELECT @MY =  DATEPART(YEAR,@mydate)

SELECT * FROM ....
```

In my stored proc I've tried it as follows but when I execute the stored proc it prompts me for parameter values:

```
USE ..
GO
..
ALTER PROCEDURE ...
(@mydate DATETIME
,@MT DATETIME
,@MY DATETIME)

AS
BEGIN ...
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT @MT = DATEPART(MONTH,@mydate)
SELECT @MY =  DATEPART(YEAR,@mydate)
---
SELECT * FROM ....
```

How do I set the parameter values in the stored proc like I would in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

I put only one parameter because the others depend on it.

**First approach**

```
USE ..
GO
..
ALTER PROCEDURE yourSP
(@mydateParam DATETIME)

AS
BEGIN ...
SELECT @mydate = @mydateParam
SELECT @MT = DATEPART(MONTH,@mydate)
SELECT @MY =  DATEPART(YEAR,@mydate)
  ---
SELECT * FROM ....
```

To call the SP:

```
DECLARE @mydateParam DATETIME
SELECT @mydateParam = GETDATE()
execute yourSP @mydateParam
```

**Second approach**

```
ALTER Procedure yourSP
@mydateParam datetime = null
AS
BEGIN ...
IF @mydateParam is null
SET @mydateParam = getdate()
SELECT @mydate = @mydateParam
SELECT @MT = DATEPART(MONTH,@mydate)
SELECT @MY =  DATEPART(YEAR,@mydate)

   ---
SELECT * FROM ....
```

To call the SP:

```
DECLARE @mydateParam DATETIME
SELECT @mydateParam = GETDATE()
execute yourSP @mydateParam
```

or

```
execute yourSP
```