# Stored Procedure parameter default value - is this a constant or a variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is my code:

```
USE [xxx]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[problemParam] 
    @StartDate INT = CONVERT(INT,(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-130,112))),
    @EndDate INT = NULL
AS  
BEGIN
```

`SSMS` is not too happy with the *default* value I've used - in the [**MSDN DEFINITION HERE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) it says that the default value needs to be a constant rather than a variable.

Is `CONVERT(INT,(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-130,112)))` a variable or a constant? It's not a variable in the traditional way I think of a variable but then again it's not a constant like `'03 jan 2013'` is.

How do I get around this? Move `CONVERT(INT,(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-130,112)))` to the client that is calling the stored procedure?

---

**EDIT**

Possible duplicate as I've just spotted this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885960/stored-procedure-parameter-default-value)

Comment: The result of `GETDATE()` *varies* by time so it cannot be constant. Use NULL/a magic value for a default, detect it & assign your expression should it match.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not sure if you're correct: surely `GETDATE()` is evaluated when it is called and then constant. See [**these blog posts**](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2008/03/01/when-a-function-is-indeed-a-constant.aspx) - sees to be debatable

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It has to be a *constant* - the value has to be computable at the time that the procedure is created, and that one computation has to provide the value that will always be used.

Look at the definition of [`sys.all_parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190340.aspx):

> `default_value`   `sql_variant`   If **`has_default_value`** is 1, the value of this column is the value of the default for the parameter; otherwise, `NULL`.

That is, whatever the default for a parameter is, it has to fit in that column.

---

As Alex K pointed out in the comments, you can just do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[problemParam] 
    @StartDate INT = NULL,
    @EndDate INT = NULL
AS  
BEGIN
   SET @StartDate = COALESCE(@StartDate,CONVERT(INT,(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-130,112))))
```

provided that `NULL` isn't intended to be a valid value for `@StartDate`.

---

As to the blog post you linked to in the comments - that's talking about a very specific context - that, the *result* of evaluating `GETDATE()` within the context of a *single* query is often considered to be constant. I don't know of many people (unlike the blog author) who would consider a separate expression inside a UDF to be part of the same query as the query that *calls* the UDF.

Comment: +1 for this solution. It's definitely a subtle difference if I change `has to be computable at the time that the procedure is created,` to `has to be computable at the time that the procedure is executed,` then as far as the sproc is concerned `GETTIME()` would be a _constant_. Like the use of `COALESCE` I used `IF @StartDate IS NULL ...`

Comment: @whytheq - if it only had to be computable at the time that the procedure was executed, what *wouldn't* be allowed at that time?

Comment: ...if it takes 2mins to execute and I set `@StartDate` to a traditional variable say `@StartDate INT = @x` then initially set @x to '01 jan 2013' and then later in the proc change it to '02 jan 2013' then I'd say that is undoubtedly a variable and not a constant; splitting hairs a bit.

Comment: Actually, `has_default` value is not working at all. There is a connect about this posted on `2006` and the issue is still not fixed - https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/234143/populate-has-default-value-in-sys-parameters

Comment: Just as a pointer for those wondering *why* `has_default` (or for that matter `DEFAULT`) is always 0 or null, this is only populated for CLR functions, not for standard stored procedures. If you want to get those parameters out, you need to do some extremely frustrating parsing work on `OBJECT_DEFINITION(<My_Sproc_ID>)`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, You have to check whether the parameter is actually NULL, before setting the value. Otherwise, it might override startdate being passed.`
`IF @StartDate IS NULL 
BEGIN 
    SET @StartDate = COALESCE(@StartDate,CONVERT(INT,(CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-130,112)))) 
END`

Comment: @VenkataramanR - `COALESCE` is "return the first non-null parameter from this list". `@StartDate` is the first parameter here. If it's non-null, it's the equivalent of a harmless `@StartDate = @StartDate` assignment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Sorry. my bad. Did not notice the `COALESCE` clause.