# Adding a default value to optional parameter of stored proce

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to have a default value for my SQL Server 2008 stored proc as below:

```
Create Process sp_Transactions1
     @earliestDate varchar(12)= CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(m,-3, getdate())) AS VARCHAR(4))  + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(m,-2, getdate())) AS varchar(2)), 2)+ '01'
As
```

But it won't compile

Is this not possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure parameter default value - is this a constant or a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137925/stored-procedure-parameter-default-value-is-this-a-constant-or-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kritner said above, the default value of parameters can be only a constant.
However, if the NULL value does not have another meaning in this context, you can use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Transactions1
     @earliestDate date=NULL
AS
IF @earliestDate IS NULL 
    SET @earliestDate=CONVERT(DATE,
        STR(YEAR(DATEADD(m,-3, getdate())),4)
        +RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(DATEADD(m,-2, getdate()))),2)
        +'01'
    )
--...
```