# Current value of a Sequence as the default parameter for a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql stored procedure which consists of two parameters. And I need to set the current value of a Sequence as the default value  of a one parameter.
So when I added default value for the parameter it gives me following error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_GET_TransformationSummary, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_GET_TransformationSummary, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

And here is my code..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GET_TransformationSummary]
@AreaCode           AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SyncId             AS INT = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, CURRENT_VALUE) FROM SYS.SEQUENCES WHERE name = 'SQ_COMMON')

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Area= @AreaCode AND SyncId = @SyncId;

END
```

And Is there any way to do this?

I need to have the `CURRENT_VALUE` of **SQ_COMMON** sequence as the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put a `SELECT` statement in `DEFAULT` parameter definition for your stored procedure. The workaround for you is to set `NULL` as `DEFAULT` value, and then check if value of `@SyncId` is null => assign it the current value from your sequence.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GET_TransformationSummary]
@AreaCode           AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SyncId             AS INT = NULL

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @SyncId IS NULL 
    SELECT @SyncId = CONVERT(INT, CURRENT_VALUE) FROM SYS.SEQUENCES WHERE name = 'SQ_COMMON'

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Area= @AreaCode AND SyncId = @SyncId;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make Syncid input parameter NUll and Inside the Store Procedure Declare another variable and assign the statement and make that Declared variable equal to Input Parameter .

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GET_TransformationSummary]
    @AreaCode           NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SyncId             INT  = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @n_syncID INT
    SET @n_syncID  = 
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, CURRENT_VALUE) FROM SYS.SEQUENCES WHERE name = 'SQ_COMMON'
    SET @n_syncID = @SyncId 

    SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE Area= @AreaCode AND SyncId = @SyncId;

    END
```

Comment: I tried this way. But I need to have it as a default parameter value as I mentioned in the question

Comment: So you are looking to add the value to input parameter.Can you tell me how many values are going to for that select statement Single or Mutliple @tarzanbappa

Comment: can you please go through this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137925/stored-procedure-parameter-default-value-is-this-a-constant-or-a-variable @tarzanbappa