# Parameters input for a SQL stored procedure without the @ sign

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored procedure named calculateLLPA that takes different parameters. When I type 
EXEC calculateLLPA, Intellisense suggest that I enter first '@variable1name VALUE, @variable2name VALUE'etc.
What I am trying to accomplish is that SQL doesn't need to require @variable1name as a parameter, but instead just the value, and if a value needs to be defaulted, then added a comma right next to it. 
Example:
calculateLLPA(30,60,,,67)
the empty fields in between commas will take the default value
instead of
calculateLLPA(@year 30, @month 60, @minute 67)
the empty fields in between commas will take the default value
Here is how my stored proc looks:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateLLPA (
@year VARCHAR(4)
@month VARCHAR(2)
@second VARCHAR(2) = '5'
@time VARCHAR(5) =  '4'
@minute VARCHAR(2)
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You should be using the parameter names anyway. It makes your code far less confusing. Not to mention if you call a procedure without naming the parameters and the list of parameters changes....your code is silently broken.

Comment: I agree with you. But it's part of a project for work and that's how they want it to be setup. 
Do you think there is a way? 
I thought I saw some stored proc/functions that take parameters directly without naming which parameter we're defining

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
exec calculateLLPA '2019', '05', default, default, '20'
```

And if a created procedure has all parameters defined like `@time VARCHAR(5) =  '4'` you can call it like this:

```
exec calculateLLPA
```

Comment: This is indeed how you would do it....but wow that is a brittle way to deal with parameters.

Comment: @SeanLange, I agree. Not recommended. But when asked ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude those variables if the value is set by default:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateLLPA (
    @year VARCHAR(4) = NULL
    ,@month VARCHAR(2) = NULL
    ,@second VARCHAR(2) = NULL
    ,@time VARCHAR(5) = NULL
    ,@minute VARCHAR(2) = NULL 

AS 
BEGIN
IF @second IS NULL
    SET @second = '5'

IF @time IS NULL
    SET @@time = '4'



--Calculate LLPA logic
END

)
```

And if you want to use default values just execute it:

```
EXEC calculateLLPA '2019', '05', NULL, NULL, '20'
```

Otherwise:

```
EXEC calculateLLPA '2019', '05', '5', '4', '20'
```

Comment: And how will you send the parameter to the procedure when you want to change second and time ?

Comment: You're alright, surfing SO found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139895/5533960) , I think the variable must be declared as NULL and set the value after in case it applies.

Comment: Is there a way for me to not type 'NULL'?
In other words, instead of this:
EXEC calculateLLPA '2019', '05', NULL, NULL, '20
Do this
EXEC calculateLLPA '2019', '05', , , '20